# Mapping the result of a recursive query in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, recursion, mapping, common-table-expression

Let's assume we have a very basic entity, say `Category`. Each category can have zero or more sub-categories (field `subcategories` of type `Set<Category>`) . I want to fetch an entire tree of categories starting at a given root. For this I use a  common table expression which returns the categories that make up the tree (I tested it separately and it works fine).

*Is there a way to automatically map this result to just one root `Category` including all subcategories present at any level?* I know I can just process the tuples manually, but I'm curious if there is a more elegant way. It seems like `@SqlResultSetMapping` or entity graphs wouldn't do the trick.

---

Some simplified code below. First, the category entity looks like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORY")
public class Categoryd {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "C_I_IDF")
    protected Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="C_PARENTCATEGORY")
    private CategoryEntity parentCategory;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parentCategory", cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE })
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
    @BatchSize(size=10)
    private List<CategoryEntity> subCategories = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

My recursive query is something like this :

```
WITH categoryrecursive (id) AS (
    SELECT C_I_IDF
    FROM CATEGORY parent
    WHERE parent.C_I_IDF = <some number>
    UNION ALL
    SELECT sub.C_I_IDF
    FROM categoryrecursive, CATEGORY sub
    WHERE sub.C_PARENTCATEGORY = categoryrecursive.id
)
SELECT cat.*
FROM categoryrecursive rc
INNER JOIN CATEGORY cat ON cat.C_I_IDF = rc.id
```

The query returns a list of categories starting at a given root.

Comment: Can you describe your table structure and the query you are thinking of in more detail? This is a common mapping that seems like just a 1:M with manyToOne back pointer (Think employee where employees are also managers). If you query on the President or root employee, you can get all employees from the company, which is why lazy is so important on 1:m relationships.

Comment: Sure, I edited the question. The category trees I'm dealing with are relatively small by design (it would be too complicated to explain why). Using a recursive one-shot query to fetch all of the categories making up a tree in one go can speed up the loading of a tree by an order of magnitude. This part works and it is tested. However I hoped to find some kind of declarative, pleasing way to do the mapping from a list of categories making up a tree to just one entity (the root), but didn't find one after going through many threads on here. The employee/manager example is equivalent.

Comment: Just loading the tree lazily works by the way, I'm just trying to speed up the whole process much like what one does with eager fetching with joins, except this time it has to be done recursively. It's the mapping back from tuples to Hibernate entities that isn't elegant, I currently manually reconstruct the tree after the query returns. I'm asking out of curiosity, in the end manual conversion to a tree works too, I just wanted to see if I'm missing some feature somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Hibernate has no knowledge (and you also can't tell it about it), that all `subCategories` are "loaded", you roughly only have one option that avoids messing with the object tree.

Configure `@BatchSize(size = 1000)` for `subCategories` with a batch size big enough (e.g. 1000), so that lazy loading can load all collections in one query. Then you can use `@SqlResultSetMapping` for the query you have and trigger the initialization of one collection, to initialize most/all collections with a single query (in addition to your recursive CTE query).

The downside here is that you need a second query, but if you don't want to reconstruct the tree yourself in memory, that's the best you can do.

I would recommend you to go the extra mile and implement the treeifying yourself with custom DTOs or even with just entities. Something like the following should work out:

```java
List<Category> list = ...
for (Category c : list) {
    c.setSubCategories(new ArrayList<>());
}
Category root = null;
for (Category c : list) {
    if (c.getParentCategory() == null) {
        root = c;
        continue;
    }
    c.getParentCategory().getSubCategories().add(c);
}
return root;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great, especially since my particular use-case is more complex (categories are linked to other entities which I also need to fetch) and your approach simplifies the code a great deal.